# I am trying to load OSM data file for a specific road segment into MATLAB and facing an error with the OpenStreetMap Functions

Tags: matlab, openstreetmap

Function used to load the osm file :
osmData = load_osm_xml('path_to_my_file.osm');

The error I am facing is as stated below:

Undefined function 'xml2struct_fex28518' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in load_osm_xml (line 27)
map_osm = xml2struct_fex28518(filename); % downloaded osm file

Error in maps_VMPS (line 45)
osmData = load_osm_xml('path_to_my_file.osm');

I am using MATLAB version 2023b and the latest file exchange Version 1.4.0.0 of OpenStreetMap Functions

Comment: That error is telling you that the file containing the function `xml2struct_fex28518` is not present or is not on MATLAB's `path`. If you read the discussions on the OpenStreetMap Functions File Exchange page, you can see that other people got the same error and were directed to a solution.